# Selecting lines which start with a string

Tags: c

I want to use this function to show lines from a file that starts with a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "RangeSelection.h"

bool RangeSelection(char * buffer, int len, char * argv[])
{
int i = 0, j, c;
char word[4];
bool is_break;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    is_break = false;       //a variable for checking if instruction break was used

    for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j)  //load three first chars
    {
        word[j] = c;
        c = getchar();  //to load chars into c
        if(c == '\0' || c == EOF)       //if there's less than 3 chars in this word, don't check it
        {
            is_break = true;
            break;
        }               //if that's EOF or new line, break
    }

    if(!is_break)
    {
        word[3] = '\0';
    }

    if(strcmp(word, argv) == 0)       //they're the same
    {
        printf("%c", word[0]);
        printf("%c", word[1]);
        printf("%c", word[2]);

        do      //do while as it will show the output at least three times
        {
            printf("%c", c);        //print that char
        }
        while((c = getchar()) != '\0' && c != EOF);
    }
    else
    {
        while((c = getchar()) != '\0' && c != EOF)     //load chars until a new line
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work as I want to. Run with parameter "xxx" it has to show only lines starting with "xxx". For this input:

```
xxx
dasfdad
xxx works
x
```

it should print only:

```
xxx
xxx works
```

while it prints:

```
xxx
dasfdad
xxx works
x
```

However, while the input is like this one:

```
dasfdad
xxx works
x
```

It prints nothing although the program ought to show

```
xxx works
```

Char * argv[] is an argument provided by the user while running the program in a console(for example xxx). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program prints the whole file when it starts with given pattern and prints nothing if it doesn't because you are not matching newline character `\n` at any time whereas you want to read your file line by line.

I would suggest you split the job into separate functions. This is how I would do it in C99 :

```
int starts_with(char *buf, char *pattern)
{
    char *p = pattern;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++)
    {
        if (!buf[i] || buf[i] != pattern[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now you can store each line inside a buffer within your `RangeSelection` function and check if each buffer start with your pattern

Comment: You're right. I was checking '\0' instead of '\n'. Now it works. Thank you! I would have done it in separate functions, however this task requires doing it in one.

Comment: You may want to move `strlen (pattern)` out of your loop test clause. While a good compiler should optimize that as a constant for the loop, you wouldn't want to call `strlen` on every iteration. Better, `size_t len = strlen (pattern); for (int i = 0; i < (int)len; i++)...`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`memcmp()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4.1) instead of `strcmp()` to make life much easier for yourself. The parameter `len` is never used in the `RangeSelection()` function. This should be removed unless it is needed for some future development. Unless the string indicated by `buffer` will be changed in the function, it would be good to use `const char *buffer` in the parameter list.

Also note that `char *argv[]` is converted to a pointer to a pointer to `char` in the function parameter list; I don't think that this is what is expected in the posted code. The function `strcmp()` expects pointers to `char` (pointers to the first elements of null-terminated character arrays), so the expression `strcmp(word, argv)` leads to undefined behavior due to type mismatch in the function call.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool filter_line(const char * buffer, const char *tag)
{
    bool is_tagged;
    size_t tag_sz = strlen(tag);
    if (strlen(buffer) < tag_sz) {
        is_tagged = false;
    } else {
        is_tagged = !memcmp(buffer, tag, tag_sz);
    }

    return is_tagged;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s line_tag\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char *filter_tag = argv[1];

    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (filter_line(line, filter_tag)) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interactions using text files as input:

test_filter_line.txt

```
xxx
dasfdad
xxx works
x

abc xxx
 xxx
```

```
λ> ./line_filter xxx < test_filter_line.txt 
xxx
xxx works
```

test_filter_line2.txt:

```
dasfdad
xxx works
x
```

```
λ> ./line_filter xxx < test_filter_line2.txt 
xxx works
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your suggestions.