# Deleting a line based on a delimiter from text file C

Tags: c, text-files, delimiter

Here I have a text file named combo.txt. I have a trouble finding a suitable way to delete the lines by delimiter. I would first take in a user input menu code, then read each line to compare with text file menu code delimiter ( C0001/C0002/C0003..). If it matches, I would like to delete that specific line in the text file. I hope anyone could suggest anything to get me started, thank you so much!

```
    C0001:Lunch Deal Set A:10.99:Burger and drink
    C0002:Lunch Deal Set B:12.99:Burger, fries, and drink
    C0003:Teatime Saver:6.99: Nugget and drink
    C0004:Dinner Deal Set A:12.99:2 pcs fried chicken and drink
    C0005:Dinner Deal Set B:14.99:2 pcs fried chicken, salad, and drink
```

So far, this is what I came up with, it's not working the way it should be. Just for some reference.

```
void delete_meal()
{
    FILE *cfptr;//declaring a file pointer for combo    
    FILE *afptr;//declaring a file pointer for combo    
    FILE *dtemp;
    FILE *tempr;

    char mcode[6];
    struct Meal meal;
    int type = 0; //Not found   

    //does the meals have to start as C  for combo and A for addon and always 5 chars only?
    printf("----------------------------\n");//function for deleting a data in the file
    printf("      DELETE MEAL\n");
    printf("----------------------------\n");
    printf("Enter meal code:\n");
    scanf("%s", mcode);//user input

    cfptr = fopen("combo.txt", "r");//creating a new file    
    while(!feof(cfptr))
    {
        fscanf(cfptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    

        if(strcmp(mcode, meal.mcode) == 0)
        {
            type = 1; //combo                    
        }
        //fscanf(cfptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
    }fclose(cfptr);

    //Couldn't found it yet, look for this item in the addon.txt
    if(type == 0){
        afptr = fopen("addon.txt", "r");        
        while(!feof(afptr))
        {
            fscanf(afptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    

            if(strcmp(mcode, meal.mcode) == 0)
            {
                type = 2; //adoon                
            }
            //fscanf(afptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
        }fclose(afptr);
    }
    printf("%d", type);

    switch(type){//switching to search which value matches the input
        case 1:            
            dtemp = fopen("deletetemp.txt", "w");//opening file for write.
            int found = 0;
            cfptr = fopen("combo.txt", "r");
            while(!feof(cfptr))
            {
                fscanf(cfptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    //reading from the file
                if(strcmp(mcode, meal.mcode) != 0)
                {
                    fscanf(dtemp, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
                }
                fscanf(cfptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
            }
            fclose(cfptr);
            remove("combo.txt");//removing one file and replacing it with another
            rename("deletetemp.txt", "combo.txt");
            fclose(dtemp);//file close
            printf("Deletion was successful.\n");         
            break;
        case 2:            
            dtemp = fopen("deletetemp.txt", "w");
            afptr = fopen("addon.txt", "r");//opening a file to read from it
            while(!feof(afptr))
            {
                fscanf(afptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
                if(strcmp(mcode, meal.mcode) != 0)
                {
                    fprintf(dtemp, "%s:%s:%f:%s\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, meal.price, meal.description);
                }
                fscanf(afptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
            }
            fclose(afptr);
            remove("addon.txt");
            rename("deletetemp.txt", "addon.txt");
            fclose(dtemp);
            printf("Deletion was successful.\n");          
            break;
        default:
            printf("This is an invalid meal code.\n");//for default value
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Why do you want to use C? This is a typical thing you do with shell scripts.

Comment: Test for eof must be immediately after a `scanf` not before, and return value of `scanf` should be controled. And you should not read two lines if you only write one.

Comment: [Don't use `while (!feof(file))` to control loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Also, [this recent answer of mine may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377254/selecting-lines-which-start-with-a-string/47378239#47378239).